# Replacing a Complex Sequence of Characters in Java

Tags: java

My requirement is that I read from a file and replace the sequence of two semicolon occurences (;;) in the file with 0 .

Problem here is that, when there are more  than two sequential occurences like  eg ';;;;;;'.

I am not able to replace 0 correctly ,any suggestions on achieving it in Java.

Sample input would be 5;4;;;4;4;;;;4;;;3;;1;5;4;5;;3;5;;5;;5;3;;;;;;;;;;;;5;

Output would be 5 4 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 4 0 0 3 0 1 5 4 5 0 3 5 0 5 0 5 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5

Comment: Use [Regular Expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: An example `System.out.println(";;;;;;".replace(";;", "0"));` will produce `000`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: What will be the regular expression for this  content to match twice occurence of a semicolon  5;4;;;4;4;;;;4;;;3;;1;5;4;5;;3;5;;5;;5;3;;;;;;;;;;;;5 
 i have written  like ([;;]re*)

Comment: What output would you expect from that. 5;40;4;40040;301;5;4;503;50505;30000005?

Comment: Yes , correct i am expecting similar  response

Comment: No 5,400;4;40004003015450350505300000000005

Comment: Please show in your question what sample input and output looks like, and what the rules of conversion are.

Comment: So if I have 3 ";" (;;;) what you want is to replace that with 2 "0's" right? Like if the consecutive length of ; is greater or equals than 2 then replace all the ; by (length - 1) - 0's

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Yes Gerado you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Untitled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String replaced = replaceSemiColons("5;4;;;4;4;;;;4;;;3;;1;5;4;5;;3;5;;5;;5;3;;;;;;;;;;;;5;");
        replaced = replaced.replace(";", "");
        System.out.println(replaced);
    }

    public static String replaceSemiColons(String string) {
        StringBuffer replaced = new StringBuffer(string);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";;+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(replaced.toString());
        while(matcher.find()){
            replaced.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), new String(new char[matcher.end() - matcher.start() - 1]).replace("\0", "0"));
            matcher = pattern.matcher(replaced.toString());
        }
        return replaced.toString();
    }
}
```

If someone has a better answer you should take it.

Comment: Thanks for the help